# npm install suddenly fails

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I have been able to install node modules locally in a project for quite some time.  All of sudden ALL attempts at installation fail, with the same type of error:

```
Homers-MacBook-Pro:test homer$ npm install bootstrap@3
/Users/homer
└── bootstrap@3.3.7 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/homer/package.json'
npm WARN homer No description
npm WARN homer No repository field.
npm WARN homer No README data
npm WARN homer No license field.
```

I'm not using a `package.json` file, just hoping to install some modules in a local `node-modules` directory. I don't understand why npm suddenly thinks it needs a `package,json` in my Home directory.

I'm on MacOS 10.12.4.  There have been no upgrades in the system or in Node since the last successful npm install a couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a `warning`, not `error`which means you can ignore it. And your package has been successfully installed.

```
npm WARN homer No description          // no description in package.json
npm WARN homer No repository field.    // no repository setted in package.json
npm WARN homer No README data          // no introcude md found
npm WARN homer No license field.       // no lisence type setted in package.json
```

Above `warn` messages is all about details of `package.json` which were caused by `package.json` not found.

---

**package.json** is a config file which stores libraries that you installed by `npm`. So that you don't have to copy/manage these libraries manually and locally.

Next time for a new environment, you can simply reprocude the denpendencies by `npm install`, and npm will read your `package.json` and reinstall packages stored in it.

---

As commented by @peteb (thanks again), while install packages via `npm install [packages]`, `npm` will try to check whether your newly installed package is listed in `package.json` . If the file doesn't exist, then this `warn message` will be shown.

Comment: This isn't totally accurate, `npm` is throwing this warning not because it is trying to save the package as a dependency but, because it wants to see if the current `package.json` already depends on it and, if so what version to install. Also, if you want to save a package as a dependency then the `--save` flag must be used like so `npm i --save <pkg>`. Just doing `npm install <pkg>` will download a copy to the `./node_modules`

Comment: @peteb bro, thanks. I was explained by some guy before like this. Sounds your comment dose more sense, I will update what's in my mind and also this post.

Comment: I should have clarified:  the installation does not fail (the module shows up in the node_modules directory in my home directory, where I normally store modules intended for global use (installed with `npm install -g`), rather than in my project directory.  I found that I can force installation in the project directory with `npm install --prefix . module-name`.